# How to define allowed IPs for JBoss management console

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm french, and it looks like the **binding**  word is used all over the world to **link** anything.

I'd like to specify which IP address is allowed to access the JBoss management web application, so I started with :

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="15.16.17.18"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
         <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Where 15.16.17.18 is my IP address. But first, it would be ok only for one IP, and probably no more for localhost.
Second, it looks like binding here means that it's linked to the IP Address of the Network card - I suppose servers can have many IP address *binded*.

Is there a way to define allowed IP with JBoss ? Or do I have to use Apache/Nginx to allow IP address based on the port ?

Comment: The JBoss community forum might be a better place to get an answer to this question.  https://community.jboss.org/en/jbossas7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inet-address you're looking at is for telling JBoss which IP Address to bind to, not which addresses are allowed to access the component.

To address your problem of only allowing certain hosts to have access to your management console, you will require something like an Apache server fronting your JBoss 7 server with the rules defined accordingly on the Apache server.